# jquery scrollpane not working

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm trying to apply the scrollpane jquery tool, which should be easy but I dont understand why its not giving any sign of life... I think I'm maybe doing some bad order in the jquery connections. This is the image of my connections in html:

```
<!-- JAVASCRIPT CONNECTIONS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/scroll_resize.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/onload.js"></script>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="script/gen_validatorv31.js" language="JavaScript"></script>  -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jScrollPane.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="_php/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
        <script src="_js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
        <!-- IE upgrade for crossbrowser -->
        <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>

        <!-- CSS CONNECTIONS -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css" media="screen"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_css/prettyPhoto.css"  media="screen" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_css/jScrollPane.css" media="screen"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_php/calendar/calendar.css" media="screen"/>


        <!-- JQ Initialization -->
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                theme: 'light_square',
                opacity:'0.70',
                counter_separator_label: ' of ',
                autoplay: false
                });
          });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({scrollbarWidth:20, scrollbarMargin:10});
            });
        </script>
```

As the [website](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) says I've inserted the neccesary files and inserted in my html a div with class .scroll-pane and I've inserted in the css the overflow: auto as they comment. I've inserted overflow-y, I doesnt work in either.

Under you will find the CSS I've applied to the div which has also assigned the class=".scroll-pane".

**CSS applied to the div which I want a special scrollbar:**

```
#music_box{
    height: 60%;
    width: 40%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```

I've spent already some hours with this small error...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the height of the scroll-pane into the css?

```
.scroll-pane{
height:100px; //example
}
```

Comment: No, but if I apply height, nothing happens. I tried also to apply .scroll-pane to #music_box with no result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Alessandro, thanks for the help but I found my problem.

Basically I was in a web which had a different javascript information than the original. So I had mixed javascript content of two version. I went slowly copying the same content of the files found in the source.

I checked other websites but [this](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html) one seems to work for me. Its also very well documented. I'm sorry I cannot recall the other website. Sorry for all the troubles...